# Starting mongodb server using npm scripts

Tags: mongodb, npm

I am starting mongodb server using cmd with the following command:

"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin/mongod.exe"

It starts the mongodb server perfectly.

Now I need to do it via npm script. Below is my package.json file:

**package.json:**

```
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"prestart": "start /b \"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin/mongod.exe\"",
"start": "ng serve | node server.js",
"build": "ng build --prod",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
}
```

Now when I hit npm start, it doesn't starts the mongodb server.

I also included the path "C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin/mongod.exe" in environment variables (both user&system).

Can anyone help me to know where I was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I read help for the start cmd command and was able to run it in a separate named window:

```
"scripts": {
    "db": "start \"ToDo MongoDB instance\" /D \"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/4.0/bin/\" mongod.exe --dbpath=\"C:/GIT/NodeJS/todo/db\""
},
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution compared to prestart.

Answer (score 0):

Try to escape the space in `Program Files` with a backslash, i.e. `Program\ Files`. I'm not a Windows guy but I hope this works there as well.

**EDIT**

As you figured out yourself, you also can enclose the path in (escaped) quotes, then resolving a directory name containing a space should work.

Comment: Thanks dr_barto. Please see my edited post. Now a new command prompt opens, but not starting the mongodb server.

Comment: Do you need the `start` command in there? I think that's what causes the additional prompt; just try to directly call the .exe: `"prestart": "\"C:/Program Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath E:/nodejs/mongo/data/db\""`

Comment: I tried. But it gives the following error: Invalid command: Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin/mongod.exe. Also I have escaped the space between program and files with carrot(^) . still no luck.

Comment: Update: using start /b stops npm to create a new cmd window. But server didn't start.

Comment: How about a backslash instead of a caret? `"prestart": "\"C:/Program\ Files/MongoDB/Server/3.6/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath E:/nodejs/mongo/data/db\""` Also you could try to exclude the parameter  (`--dbpath ...`)  from the escapted quotes. Sorry, I don't have a Windows machine around to try this out myself...

Comment: Thanks for your time dr_barto. backslash will give json parse error. Excluding --dbpath from quotes gives error: "windows cannot find --dbpath".

Comment: Update: I also moved the /data/db to C drive to make it as default. Now no need of --dbpath. still no luck.

Comment: One final attempt, have a look at this example: https://www.jokecamp.com/blog/running-local-mongodb-with-npm-scripts/ Seems to work for them :)

Comment: Tried. Still no luck. I think there is no option to start mongo server via npm. Thanks for your efforts dr_barto.

Comment: Of course there is a way, as the name of the page I posted suggest ("running-local-mongodb-with-npm-scripts"). I'm doing it myself, but on a mac.. no problems at all. Sorry we didn't figure out a way for you. I'm sure it's just about a tiny detail. One final (and now I mean it!) thought, as a workaround you could write a good old batch file for starting the server and call that batch file from the npm script.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me for Windows:

```
"scripts": {
    "db": "path_to_mongod.exe --dbpath path_to_mongodb-data_folder"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me worked on WINDOWS 10 with escape characters for backslash character and for quote character . In your case You used only for quote character. I think that may wary depending on OS and terminal you start with. I go with VSC terminal.

"scripts": {

"db": "C:\\Users\\<HERE_GOES_YOUR_USER>\\<PATH_TO_MONGO>\\mongodb\\bin\\mongod.exe --dbpath=\"c:\\Users\\<HERE_GOES_YOUR_USER>\\<PATCH_TO_DIR_WITH_DATA>\\data\" "

},