# how to run scripts using the scripts object in package.json in node.js when there is a space in the path

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, package.json, npm-scripts

In order to initialize the local mongoDB server, I have to run the following command from the root directory in the terminal :

```
/'Program Files'/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath=/MongoDB_Data
```

Now, I wish to insert a script in package.json:

```
"start_server" = "/'Program Files'/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath=/MongoDB_Data"
```

so that I only need to run `npm run create_server` to execute the command.
But it throws this error:

```
'/'Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! task-manager@1.0.0 create_server: `/'Program Files'/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath=/MongoDB_Data`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the task-manager@1.0.0 create_server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-01-31T13_36_01_276Z-debug.log
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this?
I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting mongodb server using npm scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49686131/starting-mongodb-server-using-npm-scripts)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to escape the white space with a backslash?

```
"start_server" = "/'Program\ Files'/MongoDB/Server/4.4/bin/mongod.exe --dbpath=/MongoDB_Data"
```

I'm not sure it will solve it, it's a long time since I used Windows

Comment: it throws an error in the editor (VS Code) itself, saying :- "*Invalid escape character in string.*"